# How do I change my debit card details in Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

How do I change my ATM card details in Google play as my old card has been damaged and I cannot purchase anything from my Android phone?

Answer (score 4):

As Dan has detailed in [his answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/60720/30530) you can change it via the Play Store on your phone or you can manage your payment methods via the [Google Wallet](https://wallet.google.com/manage/#paymentMethods%3a) site. This should allow you to remove your old/damaged card and add a new payment method.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the small white dialog with the green **Buy** button, press the down-arrow in the top-right corner (next to the price). Then click on **Payment options** and **Add credit or debit card**.